# Ruby On Rails--Messed Up GEMFILE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems, railstutorial.org

Please pardon my poor English to begin with. I'm new to Web-App development and I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/).

Currently I'm in the 1.5.1 Heroku setup section of the book where the author asks to edit the GEMFILE.

I have messed up my GEMFILE and I really need your help in restoring it to default. I have pasted the contents of the GEMFILE [here](http://pastebin.com/uyFJuQgm).

```
a@a:~$ rails -v
Rails 4.2.5

a@a:~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x86_64-linux]


a@a:~$ sudo mysql -v
[sudo] password for a: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 39
Server version: 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 (Ubuntu)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove you `Gemfile.lock` and

```
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.13', '< 0.5'
```

re-write  as

```
gem 'mysql2'
```